# Ag-grid - Show context menu when I hover the cursor over the grid row/cell

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'd need a solution so that when I hover the cursor over the grid row/cell then an info menu appears for that row and rows can be selected in the info menu. 
Ag-grid "Tooltip component" inappropriate, because rows cannot be clicked. 
The "Context menu" might be good, but I can't show it when I hover over it.

Example:
When I hover the cursor over "Michael Phelps", then an info menu would appear and there would be rows like "sport", "age", "country" and these rows must be selectable. 
[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncfRw.png)

Code Example for the Context menu: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-context-menu/#context-menu-example
PS: Right click to display the menu.

Any other solutions are suitable, it is not mandatory to use the "context menu".

Thank you for the help!

*Ag-grid v23.*

Comment: Just to be sure, you wrote 0 code, and you ask SO for a solution to your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use material dialog :

you can go through my stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cwydxw

You can open it on hover also.
Please let me know if it works for you